# call this instance in an inner class

Tags: java, interface, iterator, nodes, inner-classes

I'm writing a node class, and i want to make an inner node iterator class, I've written so far:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Node<E> {
  E data;
  Node<E> next;
  int current = 0;

  public Node(E data, Node<E> next){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }

  public void setNext(Node<E> next){
    this.next = next;
  }

  private class NodeIterator implements Iterator {

    /*@Override
    public boolean hasNext() {      
      Node<E> node = this;
      for(int i=1; i<current; i++){
        node = node.next;
      }
      if(node.next==null){
        current = 0;
        return false;
      }
      current++;
      return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      // code here
    }

    /*public Node<E> next() {       
      if(next==null){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
      Node<E> node = this;
      for(int i=0; i<current && node.next!=null; i++){
        node = node.next;
      }
      return node;
    }*/

    @Override
    public Node<E> next() {
      // code here
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make a node object inside the NodeIterator like this: `Node<E> node = this;`.

The commented code was written in Node class, I was implementing the Iterator in the Node class itself, but I want to make it an inner class, any suggestion how to make it like that?

Comment: So you want to access the outer node? Try `Node<E> node = Node.this;`. Also note that you might want to cache the next node in the iterator rather than iterating from the first node up to the current node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just write:

```
Node<E> node = Node.this;
```

It accesses the enclosing outer Node instance